# Installing Linux Mint on an SSD while keeping data on an HDD

Tags: linux, ssd, linux-mint

I'm currently installing Linux Mint on my laptop which has a 128GB SSD and a 1TB HDD I want to install it so that the operating system goes on the SSD and most non-program files go on the HDD.

If possible, I want to be able to choose where to install programs after Linux Mint is installed. Something similar to Windows where you just make an extra Program Files folder on the HDD and install stuff there.

Should I install normally on the SSD and then still be able to choose where to install programs later or can I use the advanced partitioning tool in the Linux Mint installer to make it more efficient in some way? I'm pretty new to Linux so any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Although it doesn't give you the ability to chose, you could either place /usr on the HDD, or look at FUSE or mhddfs filesystem, which allows you to merge multiple partitions to one mount point. For example, you could have partitions on two separate disks like /dev/sda3 and /dev/sdb1 and you could merge them as one mount point of /usr with FUSE. The drawback is you would not be able to chose programA goes on the SDD and programB goes on HDD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Linux the location of things you install is determined by the package. So everything you install will likely end up in `/usr`. At Linux installation time you can define `/usr` as being a partition on your HDD but this is IMHO a bad idea because everything will go to it including many programs and libraries you would prefer to keep in the SSD (your desktop manager, for instance).

However, links are way of life in Linux and you can after their installation move specific files or subdirectories of `/usr` to a directory on your HDD and replace them by a soft link in the original file structure. You may want to check what happens when these files receive an update.

But maybe you are worrying about a non-issue. On my Ubuntu 16.04 with a whole KDE desktop and its ancillaries plus some apps such as Libre Office, `/usr` is still under 6GB. Note also that some large applications install in `/opt` (GoogleEarth, for instance), and some will just install where you unpack them (the Eclipse IDE), so may you could just keep `/opt` on your HDD. But even then, with two Eclipse versions, Google Earth, a complete web server stack and few things, my `/opt` is only 4GB.

TL;DR: Linux is not Windows, software shares a lot of code and is less bloated. And the successive updates don't eat your disk space.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Is there a way to move certain folders from the SSD to the HDD like Pictures, Videos, and Documents like there is in windows and still have Linux know where those folders are? Would soft links work for that?

Comment: Yes, soft links are exactly what is nedeed for this. You just copy these directories to the HDD and make a soft link to them in your home (`ln -s /hdd-filesystem/Documents ~/Documents` or whatever).

Comment: It seemed to work except I restarted and now my HDD is located in /mnt/[long string of numbers and letters] instead of /media/gus/1.0TB Hard Disk and all my soft links are broken. Do you know what happened, will it happen again, and can I somehow rename the disk to something else?

Comment: `/mnt` is where fixed things (drives, network shares...) are mounted by default, while `/media` (or more accurately `/media/$your_id/`) is for plug-and-play stuff (USB disks, etc..). Nothing forbids your HDD to be mounted directly under root as `/disk2` or else. IIRc you can use your partition manager to change the mount point, or do it [manually like this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72125/correct-way-to-mount-a-hard-drive).